# Using TwitterOauth within a function

Tags: php, function

I am trying to create a small php script that pulls down a list of all user id's of people that are following/friends with a handle on twitter, for this I am using https://twitteroauth.com

I can get the id's to a file itself when I use either "friends" or "followers" individually, but when I am trying to move this script to a function I get "Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null" (line 19)

the error is triggered because this line

"                   $tweets = $twitteroauth->get($type . '/ids', array ( 'screen_name' => $term, 'cursor' => $next_cursor, 'count' => 50));
"

is being used inside a function...

I used composer and tried and got it to work outside a function.. the 2 main files are

index.php

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
require_once 'config.php';



// Pass in arguments
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
    $type = $argv[1];
    $term = $argv[2];

}
else {
    $type = $_GET['type'];
    $term = $_GET['term'];

}

    switch ($type){
        case 'timeline':
            include 'timeline.php';
        break;
        case 'followers':
        case 'friends':
            include 'f.php';        

        break;
        case 'ratelimit':
            include 'ratelimit.php';        
        break;
        case 'users_followers':
        case 'users_friends':
            include 'users.php';        
        break;
        case 'all':
        //    include 'timeline.php';
            include 'f.php';
        break;
    }
?>
```

And f.php

```
<?php

function getFrindsFollowers($term, $type){
        // create file to print follwer/friends id's to file
        $file = "files/" . $term . '_' . $type . '.csv';
        // set empty content to file
        $content = null;

        // set previous cursor
        $previous_cursor = 0;
        $next_cursor = -1;
        $loop_num = 0;

            // While statment for followers or friends calls.
            while($next_cursor != $previous_cursor && $loop_num < 15 && $next_cursor != 0){

                //use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
                //$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, oauth_access_token, oauth_access_token_secret);
                $tweets = $twitteroauth->get($type . '/ids', array ( 'screen_name' => $term, 'cursor' => $next_cursor, 'count' => 50));

                // Pause the loop for 16 min after every 15th request
                if ($loop_num % 15 == 0 && $loop_num > 15) {
                    echo "sleep mode";
                    sleep(960);
                    echo "sleep mode done";
                }

                // set cursors
                $previous_cursor = $next_cursor;

                //echo 'Previous cursor is ' . $previous_cursor;
                //echo '\n Next cursor is ' . $next_cursor;

                foreach($tweets as $key => $val) {

                    if($key == "ids"){
                        //echo $val[0];
                        foreach($val as $value){
                            $value . "\n";
                            $content .= ",\n" . $value;
                        }
                    }

                    if($key == "next_cursor"){
                        //echo "\n \n";
                        $next_cursor = $val;
                    }

                }
                $loop_num ++;
                echo "Type is now " . $type . "\n";
                echo "Loop is " . $loop_num . " for " . $type . "\n";
                file_put_contents($file, $content);
        }
}
getFrindsFollowers($term, $type);
```

?>

Is most likely a easy fix but would appreciate any guidance on how to use a get request inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

You are having trouble with scope (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

If you already have the twitteroauth variable defined outside the function, add this line at the start of it

```
global $twitteroauth;
```

This will give you access to the variable inside the function.